# ¿Por qué da el error "invalid operands of types and to binary ‘operator*’"?

Tags: c++, punteros, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Estoy haciendo un programa en C++ en el que tengo que multiplicar dos matrices, sin embargo cuando creo el metodo `operator*` y lo pruebo(estando vacio), me da el error que pone en el titulo:

```
main.cpp:28:20: error: invalid operands of types ‘matrix<float>*’ and ‘matrix<float>*’ to binary ‘operator*’
matrix<float>* b=a*a;
                 ~^~
```

Lo que tengo en el main es lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
#include "excepciones.hpp"
#include "matrix.cpp"


int main (){

    matrix<float>* a;
    int x=0, y=0;
    cout<<"introduzca el numero de filas de la matriz:"<<endl;
    cin>> x;
    cout<<"introduzca el numero de columnas de la matriz:"<<endl;
    cin>>y;

    try{

        a=new matrix<float> (x,y);
    }

    catch(exception& e){

        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    matrix<float>* b=a*a;


}
```

y el metodo operator* es el siguiente:

```
template <class T>
matrix<T>* matrix<T>::operator*(matrix<T>* a){

    return NULL;

}
```

En el hpp esta definido de la siguiente forma:

```
matrix<T>* operator*(matrix<T>* a);
```

No deberia funcionar, pues en el metodo se especifica el tipo de objeto que va a multiplicar, (estando bien), y de momento, retorna `NULL`, que es un valor que el puntero `b` puede aceptar sin problemas

Comment: Necesitas sobrecargar los sub-operadores si quieres que multiplique los valores que apuntan los punteros de otra forma no entendería la razón de multiplicar los punteros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> error: invalid operands of types ‘matrix<float>*’ and ‘matrix<float>*’ to binary ‘operator*’
> matrix<float>* b=a*a;
>                  ~^~
> ```

> ```
> error: los operandos de tipos ‘matrix<float>*’ y ‘matrix<float>*’ no son válidos para el operador binario ‘operator*’
> matrix<float>* b=a*a;
>                  ~^~
> ```

El compilador está marcando la expresión `b=a*a` como origen del error, ¿Cuáles son los tipos de las variables implicadas?

La variable `a` ha sido definida como puntero (`*`) a la plantilla `matrix` instanciada con el tipo `float`:

```
   matrix<float>* a;
// ~~~^~~ ~~^~~ ^
//     \     \   \____ puntero
//      \     \_______ float
//       \____________ plantilla 'matrix'
```

La variable `b` ha sido definida como puntero (`*`) a la plantilla `matrix` instanciada con el tipo `float`:

```
   matrix<float>* b=a*a;
// ~~~^~~ ~~^~~ ^
//     \     \   \____ puntero
//      \     \_______ float
//       \____________ plantilla 'matrix'
```

Ahora vamos a ver cómo está definido tu operador de multiplicación:

```
template <class T>
matrix<T>* matrix<T>::operator*(matrix<T>* a){
//                              ~~~^~~ ^ ^
//                                  \   \ \____ puntero
//                                   \   \_____ Tipo genérico a deducir
//                                    \________ Plantilla 'matrix'    
    return NULL;

}
```

El operador de multiplicación está definido como una función miembro que recibe un parámetro de puntero (`*`) la plantilla `matrix` instanciada con el tipo `T`. Dado que es una función miembro, a la izquierda del operador (multiplicación) deberá haber siempre una instancia de `matrix` pero tú no tienes una instancia de `matrix` ¡tienes punteros!:

```
   b=a*a
//   ^ ^
//    \ \___ puntero a 'matrix<float>' ---> matrix<float>*
//     \____ puntero a 'matrix<float>' ---> matrix<float>*
```

Te funcionará si des-referencias el puntero del operando izquierdo:

```
   b=(*a)*a
//    ^~ ^
//     \   \___ puntero a 'matrix<float>' ---> matrix<float>*
//      \______ des-referencia matrix<float>* para obtener 'matrix<float>'
```

Pero esto es un disparate, el diseño es completamente inadecuado:

- Los punteros son para manejar memoria, no deben usarse para operar aritméticamente objetos, por lo tanto:

  - Un operador aritmético no debería recibir jamás un puntero como parámetro.
  - Un operador aritmético no debería devolver jamás un puntero.
- Salvo que el operador aritmético sea también de igualación (por ejemplo `*=`) la función debería ser constante o debería estar fuera de la clase operada.

Teniendo en cuenta los puntos anteriores, tu operador debería ser así:

```
// La función no modifica el estado de la instancia ___
   template <class T> //                               \
//                                                      |
// vvvvvvvvv <--- Devuelve una instancia              vvvvv
   matrix<T> matrix<T>::operator*(const matrix<T>& a) const {
//                                ~~^~~          ^
//                                  |            |
//                 El objeto entrante es una referencia de sólo lectura.
}
```

O incluso mejor, así:

```
template <class T>
class matrix {

    template <class U>
    friend matrix<U> operator*(const matrix<U> &, const matrix<U> &);
};

template <class T>
matrix<T> operator*(const matrix<T> &a, const matrix<T> &b) {
    …
}
```

Con cualquiera de ambas opciones, tu función `main` debería quedar así:

```
int main (){

    int x=0, y=0;
    cout<<"introduzca el numero de filas de la matriz:"<<endl;
    cin>> x;
    cout<<"introduzca el numero de columnas de la matriz:"<<endl;
    cin>>y;

    // Instancia, no puntero.
    matrix<float> a{x,y};
    // Instancia, no puntero.
    matrix<float> b=a*a;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El compilador lanza el error porque el primer elemento del producto **no puede ser** un puntero. Dicho de otra forma, la sobrecarga del operador está hecha para un objeto de tipo `matrix<T>` y **no para un puntero de `matrix<T>`**.

Los siguientes ejemplos deberían solucionar el error:

```
// opcion 1: en crudo
matrix<float> * b = *a*a;

// opcion 2: con paréntesis
matrix<float> * b = (*a)*a;

// opcion 3: llamada explícita a la función
matrix<float> * b = a->operator*(a);

// opción 4: desreferenciando el puntero
matrix<float> * b = (*a).operator*(a);
```